# Space station, alarms, and malfunction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A space station has a set $A = \{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5\}$ of 5 distinct alarms that indicates 3 abnormal conditions (without distinction between them). How many ways can the alarms be associated to the abnormal conditions so that all alarms are utilized?

For instance, one abnormal condition could be indicated by the activation of alarms $\{A_1,A_3,A_4\}$.

I drew a diagram showing the abnormal conditions and the alarms associated to them:

```
    Way 1            Way 2
+------------+    +------------+    
|  A1 A3 A4  |    |   A2 A4    |
+------------+    +------------+
|  A2        |    |   A1 A5    |
+------------+    +------------+
|  A5        |    |   A3       |
+------------+    +------------+
```

But I cannot calculate the outcomes from the diagrams.

Comment: Wouldn't using distinct alarms automatically distinguish between conditions?

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, but the professor told us that conditions are undistinguishable even so... he said that this is a partitioning problem, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one alarm must be assigned to each abnormal condition.  This leaves us with two possibilities:

1. One abnormal condition has three alarms associated with it, while the two remaining abnormal conditions each have one of the remaining associated alarms.
2. Two of the abnormal conditions each have two alarms associated with them, while the third abnormal condition has the remaining alarm associated with it.

For the first case, we have $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways of assigning three alarms to one of the conditions.  Since the abnormal conditions are indistinguishable, it does not matter if we associate, say, $A_4$ with one of the remaining conditions and $A_5$ with the other or vice versa.

For the second case, we have five ways to assign a single alarm to one of the abnormal conditions.  Once we have done so, there are $\frac{1}{2} \binom{4}{2}$ ways of assigning two of the remaining alarms to another of the abnormal conditions since there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of selecting two of the alarms to be associated with a particular abnormal condition but the indistinguishability of the abnormal conditions means assigning $A_1$ and $A_2$ to one of these conditions and $A_3$ and $A_4$ to the other has the same effect as doing the reverse.  Thus, there are $5 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\binom{4}{2} = 5 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 6 = 15$ possible assignments.

Since the two cases are disjoint, we have $10 + 15 = 25$ possible ways of assigning the five distinct alarms to the three indistinguishable conditions.

That said, I feel that assigning distinguishable alarms to the abnormal conditions has the effect of distinguishing between the abnormal conditions.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the ball and urn identity and get \begin{align}
_{5+3-1}C_{5} &=_7C_5\\
&= \frac{7!}{(7-5)!5!}\\
&=21
\end{align}